# Kivy OS X - SDL2 provider - Keyboard modifiers don't work

Tags: python, kivy

I use Mac OS X 10.12 Sierra, Kivy 1.9.1, Python 2.7.3

Modifiers don't work for following code:

```
#......
def __init__(self):
    self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
    self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.on_key_down_cb)

def on_key_down_cb(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
    print(keycode)
    print(text)
    print(modifiers)
```

When I press "a", "b", "c", HOLD "shift" and "a", "b", "c"

I expect abcABC
(concatenated "text" argument)

But output is abcİabc

--output:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /Users/jares/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-02-07_50.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.13 (default, Dec 18 2016, 07:03:39) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_imageio, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <2.1 INTEL-10.18.65>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Intel Inc.>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Intel Iris Pro OpenGL Engine>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 1
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <1.20>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
(97, 'a')
a
[]
(98, 'b')
b
[]
(99, 'c')
c
[]
(304, 'shift')
İ
[]
(97, 'a')
a
['shift']
(98, 'b')
b
['shift']
(99, 'c')
c
['shift']
```

Is there any configuration which affects keyboard behaviour?

Comment: Try to use english-only keyboard first if it produces the same output. Also a useful thing might be to update to the latest Kivy (1.9.2) and check if it's fixed there. I don't experience such an issue, but I don't have OSX either.

Comment: I just figured it out! Keyboard.on_textinput event is the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Use on_textinput instead

```
Keyboard.bind(on_textinput=cb)
```